# Angular 2 passing value between components

Tags: angular

I have 4 components on my Angular 2 app. Components are Header, Footer, Navigation and Content. I have a button in the header component and I want to show/hide the content in the navigation component when user click on the button from the header component. I want to know that when I click the button from the header how to pass the `Boolean` value from header component to the navigation component. All the components have their own html templates. Let me know what is the way to pass the toggle value from header to navigation component.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the code that shows your components, their template and how they are related.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of `sharedservice` and `sharedobject` as shown below.

**[working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9VhDW442Keld9OTSA63O?p=preview)**

***sharedService.ts***

```
export interface ImyInterface {
   show:boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class sharedService {
  showhide:ImyInterface={show:true};

  hide(){
        this.showhide.show=!this.showhide.show;
  }
}
```

***header.ts (content.ts)***

```
import {Component,Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {sharedService} from 'src/sharedService';

@Component({
  selector: 'thecontent',
    template: `
    <div>Header Component <button (click)=showhide()>show/hide</button></div>
    `
})
export class TheContent {
  constructor(private ss: sharedService) {
    console.log("content started");
  }
  showhide() {
    this.ss.hide();
  }
}
```

***navigation.ts (nav.ts)***

```
import {Component,bind} from 'angular2/core';
import {sharedService} from 'src/sharedService';

@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  template: `
  <style>
    .bk{
          background-color:black;
          color:white;
    }
  </style>
  <div>Navigation Component </div>
  <div [class.bk]="true" *ngIf="showHide.show"> Showing </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  `
})
export class Navbar {
  showHide:ImyInterface;
  constructor(ss: sharedService) {
    this.showHide=ss.showhide;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried the code which you provided. I am getting this error `EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined in [showHide.show in edockNavigationComponent@3:32]`

Comment: have you written this line in `export class Navbar{  showHide:ImyInterface; ... ... ...}` ? and same interface in `sharedService`. Check my demo properly.

Comment: Very nice.  I like that you use an API, `hide()`, rather than modifying the `show` property directly in `showhide()`.  I think I like the usage of an interface.  This seems more efficient than using another API on the service to get the value.  However, if you did use an API to get the current value of `show` (e.g., `*ngIf="ss.getShowValue()`), then you wouldn't need to wrap the boolean in an object.  I'm not sure which I like better... efficiency or more encapsulation.  Your thoughts?

Comment: @MarkRajcok glad thtat you like it. But can you please fork plunk n show me what do you want? (as there can be different ways)

Comment: It's not "what I want", but more like... what do you think of this approach?: http://plnkr.co/edit/n7MxhJoLDCLZbl4mOxjX?p=preview  I call a function on the service in the NgIf expression, rather than rely on a shared reference type.

Comment: yes absolutely this approach can be used and i think its better having no doubt but I just wanted to show him using `sharedObject` so he can use that concept somewhere else( I think probably one has to deal with `sharedobject` while making angular2 app - but it depends) because using sharedobject you will be able to deal with more properties which can be helpful for a big project. So the final thing is he can go with any way....